# SyntaxError on Creating a container in React Native

Tags: react-native

In this tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial) the author stated to put in the following:

Next add the following class below the HelloWorld component:

```
class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

    );
  }
}
```

But when I try to do that, I get the following issue:

[Error Screen][2]

I am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');

var styles = ReactNative.StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 80
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});


class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactNative.Text style={styles.text}>Hello World (Again)    </ReactNative.Text>;
  }
}

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

    );
  }
}

ReactNative.AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', function() { return PropertyFinderApp });
```

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is your empty return statement for the PropertyFinderApp component: you have to return either null or an actual React element (usually through JSX). In general, the formatting for that whole tutorial is broken, and I'd suggest looking for a different one. Either way, note that the error screen you tried attaching doesn't actually show up, and you might want to try following https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28533 to get it working.

Comment: Yeah that is in fact the issue. I am not really able to figure out how he did the container to render that screen :-\

Do you know of another guide?